# Table design in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Can I create design like shown in below figure by using default controls given in windows phone 8.1 SDK.

I tries following control:

```
<Border />
<StackPanel />
<Line />
```

But unable to find exact design shown. Shown design made by using HTMTL table tag where text `Sign in` is `table header` and other are `table rows`. Do we have `table` control?
[image]

Comment: Have a look at `Grid`.

Comment: Are you looking for a [Grid panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295203.aspx)? There are rows/columns.

Comment: @Romasz Grid and Grid Panel don't have header.

Comment: But you can define additional row and put there your header. You can also make your own UserControl with Header property basing on grid layout. Take a look at default *Template* of any build in control, they consist of basic panels - StackPanel/Grid and you will see how header is constructed.